# Vaadin with custom layout and JavaScript component

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I have Vaadin custom layout to which I want to add a JavaScript component - jQuery bxSlider.

On my page1.html I have list:

```
        <div id="slider">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li><img src="../img/slide1.jpg" width="1184" height="523"
                    alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="../img/slide1.jpg" width="1184" height="523"
                    alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="../img/slide1.jpg" width="1184" height="523"
                    alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="../img/slide1.jpg" width="1184" height="523"
                    alt=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

In my View I'm trying to execute JS:

```
CustomLayout cl = new CustomLayout("page1");
....
addComponent(cl);
this.getWindow().executeJavaScript("$(document).ready(function(){$('.bxslider').bxSlider();});");
```

But nothing happens - Images are not wrapped into slider.
How can I run this JS in Vaadin app?

Comment: i doubt there will a ready event at this point in vaadin.  you could try to run just `$('.bxslider').bxSlider()` at this point.  And if this also fails, you might be better off writing your own javascript component, because you are master of the timing and the state.

Comment: Well, it works - but only when Slider is in main View. When I try to run it on other view (here: page1) it does nothing... Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin 7:

- First you need to import your library into folder:
  WebContent/VAADIN/js/script.js
- Then include it in your UI with annotation: `@JavaScript(
  "vaadin://js/script.js" })` - *for privious path example*
- Execute it when needed with:
  `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("myFunction()");`

Comment: Sorry, this anwser was for Vaadin 7